# Adding OR to the middle of google if and formula?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to add an or function to a formula that works. I need to only edit one small part of the last 2 sections.

```
=0.2+if(and(O4>0,N4>1),0.3)+if(and(O4>0,N4>1,(T4*24)>19,(S4*24)>7,K4>2),0.3)+if(and(O4>0,N4>1,(U4*24)>29,(T4*24)>29,(S4*24)>7,K4>3),0.1)+if(and(O4>0,N4>1,(U4*24)>39,(T4*24)>39,(S4*24)>7,K4>4),0.1)+if(and(O4>0,N4>1,(U4*24)>49,(T4*24)>49,(S4*24)>9,**K4>4,I4>4**),0.05)+if(and(O4>0,N4>1,(U4*24)>49,(T4*24)>49,(S4*24)>9,**K4>4,I4>4**),0.05)
```

I need the formula to be if K4 and I4 are above 4 OR  R4 is above 10 then continue I have to add the Or R4 part to the furmula. but I cant figure out how to put the or in the middle of the formula.

Here is my sheet:
​https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D-J-z-RM9Q9tiI4Fy-Dzyu-hb4Mpft65ARgC2PVmUYI/edit?usp=sharing​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=0.2+
 IF( (O4>0) * (N4>1), 0.3, 0)+
 IF( (O4>0) * (N4>1) * ((T4*24)>19) * ((S4*24)>7) * (K4>2), 0.3, 0)+
 IF( (O4>0) * (N4>1) * ((U4*24)>29) * ((T4*24)>29) * ((S4*24)>7) * (K4>3), 0.1, 0)+
 IF( (O4>0) * (N4>1) * ((U4*24)>39) * ((T4*24)>39) * ((S4*24)>7) * (K4>4), 0.1, 0)+
 IF(((O4>0) * (N4>1) * ((U4*24)>49) * ((T4*24)>49) * ((S4*24)>9)) * (((K4>4) * (I4>4)) + (R4>9)), 0.05, 0)+
 IF(((O4>0) * (N4>1) * ((U4*24)>49) * ((T4*24)>59) * ((S4*24)>9)) * (((K4>4) * (I4>4)) + (R4>9)), 0.05, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the `OR()` as follows;

```
=0.2+if(and(O4>0,N4>1),0.3)+if(and(O4>0,N4>1,(T4*24)>19,(S4*24)>7,K4>2),0.3)+if(and(O4>0,N4>1,(U4*24)>29,(T4*24)>29,(S4*24)>7,K4>3),0.1)+if(and(O4>0,N4>1,(U4*24)>39,(T4*24)>39,(S4*24)>7,K4>4),0.1)+if(OR(and(O4>0,N4>1,(U4*24)>49,(T4*24)>49,(S4*24)>9,K4>4,I4>4),R4 > 10),0.05)+if(and(O4>0,N4>1,(U4*24)>49,(T4*24)>49,(S4*24)>9,K4>4,I4>4),0.05)
```

Comment: James that doesnt work. If I remove the k4 or I4 and add the R4 it does not count it